# nested resources routing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably pretty simple, but I havent messed with rails in a while and I'm not sure if things have changed that much since 3.2

So I have two models, reports and receipts. Each report has many receipts so my models look like:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :receipts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :receipts, :allow_destroy => true

    attr_protected :id

end
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :report

    attr_protected :id

    validates_presence_of :vendor, :date, :description, :amount, :acctCode
end
```

My receipts controller is located in the root of the controller folder and has all the actions listed out (it was generated by the scaffold)

My routes have:

```
root :to => "index#index"

resources :reports do
    resources :receipts
end
```

and my link_to looks like this :

```
<%= link_to 'New Receipt', new_report_receipt_path, :class=>"btn btn-success" %>
```

which gives me the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"receipts"}
```

I ran rake routes and I got the following:

```
     report_receipts GET    /reports/:report_id/receipts(.:format)          receipts#index
                     POST   /reports/:report_id/receipts(.:format)          receipts#create
  new_report_receipt GET    /reports/:report_id/receipts/new(.:format)      receipts#new
 edit_report_receipt GET    /reports/:report_id/receipts/:id/edit(.:format) receipts#edit
      report_receipt GET    /reports/:report_id/receipts/:id(.:format)      receipts#show
                     PUT    /reports/:report_id/receipts/:id(.:format)      receipts#update
                     DELETE /reports/:report_id/receipts/:id(.:format)      receipts#destroy
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to give the report id in your route. It depends on how you access your report in your view, but it must be something like :
`new_report_receipt_path(@report)`

Comment: You simply forgot to give the report id in your route. It depends on how you access your report in your view, but it must be something like :
`new_report_receipt_path(@report)`

Ah ok yeah that makes sense, I added @report (thats what I've named the variable in my controller) but now I get the error `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"receipts", :report_id=>#<Report id: nil, filename: nil, company: nil, stardDate: nil, endDate: nil, purpose: nil, milage: nil, cashAdvance: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}`

Comment: It seems that your record is not saved in your db... i think you don't want the id of your object to be protected : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_protected/class

Comment: actually, i was getting that error because the @record hadnt been created yet. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

new_report_receipts_path

? Note the s, i.e.

> link_to 'New Receipt', new_report_receipts_path, :class=>"btn
>   btn-success"

Comment: nah, rake routes gives me: `new_report_receipt` and since its creating a new record, the path name is singular. if it were the index then it would have an 's'

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I think siekfried's answer is correct though.